# code for makin a dropdownlist dynamically added value permanent to make it appear evrytime the dropdownloads

Tags: dynamic, drop-down-menu

code for makin a dropdownlist dynamically added value permanent to make it appear evrytime the dropdownloads

protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtSelectUrTime.Visible = false;
        btnAdd.Visible = false;

```
    DropDownList7.Items.Remove(DropDownList7.SelectedItem);

    DropDownList7.Items.Add(new ListItem(txtSelectUrTime.Text));
    DropDownList16.Items.Add(new ListItem(txtSelectUrTime.Text));
    DropDownList21.Items.Add(new ListItem(txtSelectUrTime.Text));
    DropDownList22.Items.Add(new ListItem(txtSelectUrTime.Text));
    DropDownList23.Items.Add(new ListItem(txtSelectUrTime.Text));
    DropDownList24.Items.Add(new ListItem(txtSelectUrTime.Text));

}
```

txtselecturtime text is the field wherin the user upadtes a timeslot vaue during runtime n on the button click this value gets added to all the dropdownlists..

the problem with this code is that the values are visible only durin runtime..
after i reload that proj..n execute it.. the dynamically added value by user is not displayed inspite of the fact that it was displayed previously.